# Going Through JSON data given Through API call with c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, api

I am currently learning C# and how to use API's. One of the API's i need to use comes from TVmaze. However I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the JSON data I've been given with this example API call: http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls

Basically what I am trying to do is grab the Show Name, Days that it Airs and Time of day it Airs and store them within strings or a List (more or less for storing the data about what days it airs in cause multiple)

Any help is appreciated, and I do apologize in advance if this question is super vague and that I don't have anything to show or work off of at the moment.

Edit: Did I quick right up on where I am up to.

```
namespace MajorProjectTvApplication
{
    public class LoadTVShows
    {
        public string name;
        public string summary;
        public string time;
        public string days;

        public async Task<bool> GetAPI(string worldLocation)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync("");
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var rawTvListings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenTVGuideResponse>(responseString);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly are you stuck? Have you deserialised the JSON into a C# object yet? That's the first step. Then you can manipulate it like any other object and access its properties etc. You should be able to find tutorials showing you the basic concepts already. Have you tried anything? Please be more specific about where the exact problem is, and show the code you have written so far.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have made an edit to my post on where I am currently up to. I have the data deserialized, its just then taken it from there and accessing the specific data

Comment: You're deserializing a list so should be var rawTvListings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OpenTVGuideResponse>>(responseString); Now rawTvListings will be a list of OpenTVGuideResponse type with which you can iterate through

Comment: I think auburg is onto something - the JSON is in the form of an array or list, so the first step would be to deserialise it into a list. And can we see the definition of the OpenTVGuideResponse class too please?

Comment: I am unsure on what information you are after, as I don't have a class for that definition yet.

Comment: How does `OpenTVGuideResponse` look like?

Comment: well you're going to need to define a class (or likely classes, to cope with the sub-sections of the data) which match the structure of the JSON - at minimum it needs to include the properties you specifically want access to, then you can deserialise to it. deserialisation works by doing a 1-1 mapping between the items in the JSON and the properties in the class.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to create POCO objects that contain properties that you care about. For example something like this:

```
public class Details
{
    public Show show { get; set; }
}
public class Show
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Schedule schedule { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
}
public class Schedule
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public List<string> days { get; set;}
}
```

It is important that the names of properties are exactly the same like those in the JSON file. The structure of your objects also metters. Should be like in the JSON file. Otherwise it'll fail to deserialize. If you really want to have different name you need to use data annotation such as this one.

```
[JsonPropertyName("name")]
public string DifferentNameStillWorks { get; set; }
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON to these objects. The JsonSerializer will ignore all the data that you're not interested in. As a result you'll get the list of Details.

```
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=girls").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var listOfDetails = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Details>>(result);
    }
```

Don't forget `using System.Text.Json;` at the beginning.

PS Check out why you should not put HttpClient into using statement. Eg. here: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 1):

I would normally use the approach given by @LilacBlue in their answer but since the json contains a lot of properties and you're only interested in a few of them, you might not want to define the whole model.

An alternative approach would be to install the NuGet package `Newtonsoft.Json` and try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.tvmaze.com/") };
            var response = await client.GetAsync("search/shows?q=girls");
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var shows = JArray.Parse(json);
            var times = shows.Children()
                .Select(c => c["show"])
                .Select(show => new Show()
                {
                    Name = show["name"].ToString(),
                    Time = show["schedule"]["time"].ToString(),
                    Days = show["schedule"]["days"].Children().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Show
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Days { get; set; }
    }
}
```